# Seaborn scatterplot size and jitter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have the following code for a scatter graph

```
dimens = (12, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=dimens)
sns.scatterplot(data = information, x = 'latitude', y = 'longitude', hue="genre", s=200,
                x_jitter=4, y_jitter=4, ax=ax)
```

No matter what I change the jitter to, the plots still remain very close. Whats wrong with it?

Example dataframe:

```
 store      longitude       latitude      genre
mcdonalds    140.232323      40.434343     all
kfc          140.232323      40.434343     chicken
burgerking   138.434343      35.545433     burger
fiveguys     137.323984      36.543322     burger
```

Comment: please share some data so that we can try it out by ourselves.

Comment: I have added a dataframe.

Answer (score 17):

In the [help page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), it writes:

> {x,y}_jitterbooleans or floats Currently non-functional

You can either add a new column or do it on the fly:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

information = pd.DataFrame({'store':['mcdonalds','kfc','burgerking','fiveguys'],
                   'longitude':[140.232323,140.232323,138.434343,137.323984],
                   'latitude':[40.434343,40.434343,35.545433,36.543322],
                   'genre':['all','chicken','burger','burger']})

def jitter(values,j):
    return values + np.random.normal(j,0.1,values.shape)

sns.scatterplot(x = jitter(information.latitude,2), 
                y = jitter(information.longitude,2),
                hue=information.genre,s=200,alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The parameter `s=200` sets the individual scatter points to a very large size.
Adding 4 points of jitter is very little compared to that.

Comment: I have lowered my s, yet the same problem still occurs. I have added a dataframe.